# The Picard-Lindelof Existence theorem.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, lipschitz-functions

The version of theorem I am using.

> Let $t_0 \in \mathbb{R},a>0,R>0,y_0 \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $f:[t_0,t_0 + a] \times B_R(y_0) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ (jointly) continuous, $|f(t,y)| \leq M\quad (t\in [t_0,t_0+a] y \in B_R(y_0)) $ and $\alpha = \min(a,\frac{R}{M})$ Assume also that there is an $L>0$ such that the Lipschitz condition.
>   $$
> |f(t,y)-f(t,z)|\leq|y-z|\quad (t\in [t_0,t_0+a] y \in B_R(y_0))
> $$ 
>   holds, then the IVP
>   $$
> u'(t) = f(t,u(t))   ,\quad u(t_0) = y_0
> $$ 
>   has a unique solution  on $[t_0,t_0+a]$

---

The IVP I am investigating.

$$\frac{du}{dx} = \frac{1}{u} + x, u(0) = 1$$

$$\text{Does the IVP have a unique solution on }  (0,\infty)?? $$

---

I think I have misused the theorem, because I have said.

We can define $f[0,a] \times B_{\frac{1}{2}}(1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$, noting that we can take $a$ as big as we like. and

$$|f(x,u)|\leq 2+a$$

also  $$|f(x,u)- f(x,v)|\leq4|u-v|$$ 
So $f$ is lipschitz on the defined intervals.

But since we can take a as large as we like then the result follows

Should this be true for any $R>0$??

Comment: The thing to be careful of here is that $f(x,u)=1/u+x$ is not a globally Lipschitz function of $u$. It is only a locally Lipschitz function of $u$, with problems occurring near $0$. However, one can argue that any solution to your problem is an increasing function, so one can treat the domain of $f$ as being $[0,\infty) \times [1,\infty)$. On this restricted domain, $f$ is Lipschitz in $u$ and everything goes through.

Comment: Without doing something like this, you only get local existence, not global existence, because there is no guarantee that you do not hit some point where initial conditions give non-uniqueness (e.g. $y=0$ in $y'=\sqrt{|y|}$) or a finite time blowup (e.g. $y'=1+y^2$).

Comment: @Ian A minor comment: a "point where initial conditions give non-uniqueness" never changes the maximal interval. In other words, even with nonuniqueness, the maximal interval only depends on the initial condition, being sufficient for it that the vector field is continuous.

Comment: @Jonas The maximal interval where what, exactly, happens? My point is exemplified by $y'=3|y|^{1/3},y(0)=-1$. In this case you have a unique solution on $(-\infty,1]$ (namely $y=x^3$) and then nonuniqueness kicks in.

Comment: I guess that my comment is quite clear, there is no possible confusion. In other words, that part of your comment is certainly wrong, the rest is fine.

Comment: @Jonas I am actually confused by it because I don't know what you mean by "maximal interval". Do you mean the maximal interval of *existence*?

Comment: Indeed, "maximal interval" is the same as "maximal interval of existence".

Comment: As long as I take the solution to be an increasing function, my argument holds?

Comment: @Jonas Except I never said anything about the maximal interval. All I was saying is that you do not have global uniqueness even when you have local uniqueness, which is illustrated by the problem $y'=3|y|^{1/3},y(0)=-1$.

Comment: @HMPARTICLE Not exactly, it doesn't really have anything to do with monotonicity inherently. It just has to do with the fact that the dynamics of the solution remain in a region of the domain of $f$ where $f$ is Lipschitz in $u$ and continuous in $x$. This could happen even if the dynamics were oscillatory, say.

Comment: Yes you did. Let me clarify: your statement "that you do not hit some point where initial conditions give non-uniqueness" is wrong, since the maximal interval only depends on the initial condition. Certainly you were talking about the maximal interval right? Otherwise it should be clarified.

Comment: @Jonas Oh, I'm sorry, I just said the completely wrong thing in the second comment, I meant to say "local uniqueness, not global uniqueness".

Comment: @Ian I regret if it sounded harsh in the beginning. In fact I am a big fan of your answers in the site, just thought that I should comment on this time.

Comment: There is a typo in the claims of the theorem. The interval that you get a unique solution on is $[t_0,t_0+α]$, $α=\min(a,\frac RM)$, since for a larger interval you can not guarantee that the solution stays inside the ball of radius $R$.

Comment: Ah I see where I was going wrong now! Regardless of whether we can take $a$ as large as we like, we are still restricted by this fact!

Comment: Out of interest, Is there a way to find a solution to this system I tried substituting $x = e^z$ but then realised that $0 = e^z$ is nuts.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha gives an implicit solution in terms of Airy functions...